# Laravel 5 Query Builder Left Join

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-query-builder

I want to execute following mysql command in laravel

```
SELECT stars.*, SUM(points.amount) AS total_points
FROM stars
LEFT JOIN points ON stars.id = points.star_id 
GROUP BY stars.id
```

So I wrote:

```
\DB::table('stars')
            ->leftJoin('points', 'stars.id', '=', 'points.star_id')
            ->select(\DB::raw("stars.*, SUM('points.amount') AS total_points"))
            ->groupBY('stars.id')
            ->get();
```

when I dump and die the result, I see total_points is 0.0. What's Wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps the problem in quotation marks?

```
->select(\DB::raw("stars.*, SUM('points.amount') AS total_points"))
```

Correctly:

```
->select(\DB::raw("stars.*, SUM(points.amount) AS total_points"))
```

Simple variant:

```
->selectRaw('stars.*, SUM(points.amount) AS total_points')
```